# How to get all the options from drop down using Selenium WebDriver java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, dropdown

```
<select id="vehicleTypeName" class="custom-select" name="vehicleTypeName">
<option value="">-Select Style-</option>
<option value="Hatchback">Hatchback Cars</option>
<option value="Sedans">Sedan Cars</option>
<option value="MUV">MPV Cars</option>
<option value="Sport Utilities">SUV Cars</option>
<option value="Luxury Vehicles">Luxury Cars</option>
<option value="Hybrids">Hybrid Cars</option>
<option value="Minivans">Minivans</option>
<option value="Convertibles">Convertible Cars</option>
<option value="Coupe">Coupe Cars</option>
</select>
```

i have used this code to validate the options

```
String label=driver.findElement(By.id("vehicleTypeName")).getText();

logger.info("Brand names are \t" + label );
```

But it is printing all the brands including "-Select Style-" this item. but  I don't want to print this "-Select Style-" value.but  I want to validate only brand names. please help me  with this.

Answer (score 6):

I just wrote a quick function for you. hope it helps!

```
/**
 * Get all <code><option/></code> innerHTML attributes
 *
 */
List<String> getAllOptions(By by) {
    List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (WebElement option : new Select(driver.findElement(by)).getOptions()) {
        String txt = option.getText();
        if (option.getAttribute("value") != "") options.add(option.getText());
    }
    return options;
}
```

Now executing:

```
getAllOptions(By.id("vehicleTypeName"));
```

will return:

```
["Hatchback Cars", "Sedan Cars"...] // of course in List<> representation..
```

Answer (score 3):

Can Use below use it worked for me

```
Select dropDown = new Select(Driver.findElement()));
List<WebElement> e = dropDown.getOptions();
int itemCount = e.size();

for(int l = 0; l < itemCount; l++)
{
    System.out.println(e.get(l).getText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution;

`String label = driver.findElement(By.id("vehicleTypeName")).getText().replace("-Select Style-", "");`

BTW, it's not a good practice.

Comment: I personally wouldn't use this, it doesn't allow future changes without any code changes. We should really be checking the underlying value. But it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(
          By.xpath("//*[@id="vehicleTypeName"]/option"));
```

Now you can easily construct a new `List` from `options` excluding the first element:

```
List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=1; i<options.size(); i++) {
    text.add(options.get(i).getText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your xpath here"));
Select select = new Select(element);
List<WebElement> list = select.getOptions();
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)        
    {
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
    }
```

All the above lines are continuous piece of code.
Working :
a) Point 1 and 2 are straight forward to locate a Drop down box
b) In point 3, we create a List variable 'list' and stuff all the values in the drop down.
c) In the for loop, we pick each element according to their index using get(i) and use getText() to acquire the text it holds.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hi the below method will solve your problem. It will be easy for you to use

```
 public List<String> getAllValues() throws InterruptedException
 {

    Select sel = new Select(DomainName);
    List<WebElement> we = sel.getOptions();
    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(WebElement a : we)
    {
        if(!a.getText().equals("Select")){
            ls.add(a.getText());
        }
    }
    return ls;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
String label=driver.findElement(By.id("vehicleTypeName"));
Select labelSelector = new Select(label);
labelSelector.deselectByValue("");
List<WebElement> allOptions =  labelSelector.getOptions();
```

You could then use the List and it should contain all options that have something in the `value` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the possible ways to do it:

**1- By removing the first Option from the list**

```
//Locating the Select Dropdown for Vehicle Type
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("vehicleTypeName")));

//Getting all the options present in the dropdown.
List<WebElement> list = sel.getOptions();

//Removing the first dropdown option from the list, i.e., '-Select Style-'
list.remove(sel.getFirstSelectedOption());

//Printing the List
System.out.println("The list without the first element, i.e., 'Select Type' is as under: ");

for(WebElement ele: list)
    System.out.println(ele.getText());
```

**2- By removing the option that has text "-Select Style-"**

```
//Locating the Select Dropdown for Vehicle Type
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("vehicleTypeName")));

//Getting all the options present in the dropdown.
List<WebElement> list = sel.getOptions();

//Removing the dropdown option '-Select Style-' from the list
Iterator<WebElement> iter = list.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    if(iter.next().getText().equals("-Select Style-")){
        iter.remove();
        break;
    }
}

//Printing the List
System.out.println("The list without the first element, i.e., 'Select Type' is as under: ");
for(WebElement ele: list)
    System.out.println(ele.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
WebElement lelement = driver.findElement(By.id("vehicleTypeName"));    
Select oSelect = new Select(lelement);
java.util.List <WebElement> elementCount = oSelect.getOptions();
int iSize = elementCount.size();
String [] arrdropdown= new String [iSize];          
for (int j = 0; j < iSize; j++) 
{
    arrdropdown[j]=elementCount.get(j).getText();
}
logger.info("Brand names are \t" + Arrays.toString(arrdropdown));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//**Selecting all Option Using tagName as Option in List and run foreach loop**
for(WebElement Element:driver.findElements(By.tagName("option")))
{System.out.println(Element.getText());}
```